# Fluid mechanics- Force required to keep the gate closed

Tags: fluid-mechanics, moments

[image]

I have to answer the following question which is (image shown above)
"what is the force to keep the rectangular gate closed? in N/M"

This is all the information I have to solve the question. I understand there will be use of moments. I just require help understanding the question.

[image]

Comment: What don't you understand? To the left you have a large column of water. This will apply pressure on the gate, which will want to open by rotating around the hinge at the bottom (near the box). What is the force $F$ applied at the top of the gate necessary to keep it from opening?

Comment: ... then start by listing all forces acting on your gate and from there, find the corresponding moments. we tend to close homework questions without sewrious effort by the poster. (I'm also almost sure one piece of information is missing, or your answer eill be in a weird unit like N/m ;-)

Comment: What's wrong with N/m?

Comment: @Adam: He's probably talking about the need for a "width" of the gate. If the gate is 1m wide, you'll need a certain force X to keep the gate closed. If the gate is 2m wide, you'll need 2X. Without the width of the gate, you'll have to find F in force per unit of width, as opposed to the expected unit of simply force.

Comment: Also, I realize that I'm in doubt as to where the hinge actually is. Is it at the bottom, as I previously assumed, or at the spot 1.35m from the bottom? If it's at the bottom, then what's that other point? If it's at the other point, then wouldn't the force be unnecessary, since the pressure will be greater below the hinge (and the slight off-center spot of the hinge probably isn't enough to matter)?

Comment: @Wasabi I had the same thought: "Assume the gate rotates about the pin near the center.  Then the water pressure force on the lower half is greater than that on the upper and no force is needed to keep it closed.

Comment: apologies for the late response, the questions answer will be in n/m when looking at the solution ( only have a final answer) i have attempted and the an issue i have come across is the use of the centre of pressure equation i have posted in the question where (yc is the centroid) (yp is the centre of pressure) (Ic is the second moment of area about the centroid (bd^3/12) ) and A is the area.    an issue here is how can i implement the area? where there is still an unknown?

Comment: plus i think i have spotted an issue with the diagram as the distance "1.35" should be "1.5m" as is half way down the gate which is 3m in total. I've emailed the lecturer to confirm but otherwise would continue to solve with this correction.    regards.

Comment: Careful.  The water pressure force does not act at halfway up the gate This can be solved with centroids and moments and such, but for a simple case like this, you might want to look into "hydrostatic pressure prism."

Answer (score -5, accepted):

[image]

[image]

Hope you understand!
If any questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: While your attempts to answer the question are appreciated, it is far better to type the steps into the answer and explain why / what you're doing.  Pasting images of the work required to solve the problem doesn't teach the asker how to solve the problem themselves.  And users on mobile devices may have image downloads blocked, so they will not be able to see your work.

Comment: on the other hand an answr like this will force the op to read it and not just cut paste and submit as homework soluiton..

Comment: Hello Glen, I didn't knew how to add the 2nd image in the same answer. That's why i gave two answers. And typing the formula with subscripts is difficult, hence i solved it on a page and pasted the image.

Comment: Solving it on a page by using different colour pens and pasting the image is a lot of effort. And its sad to see that the effort is not being appreciated. Plus giving such a solution is better than just providing steps. It gives a better understanding of the solution.

Comment: @SiddharthRai Your solution is essentially just you working through the steps.  It's also incredibly hard to read on mobile.  Beyond this, it's generally not well received to answer questions where the person asking has not made their efforts clear.  Instead it's better to leave unanswered with comments explaining why.  That way this site isn't full of people trying to get us to do their homework.

Answer (score 0):

Is there more information from the question, there is enough to solve but it never hurts to have more info.

The way I see this problem is you have to balance the applied force F with the distributed load from the water, this gets a little complicated because the water is fighting itself, the water at heights (from the bottom) 1.2m - 1.35m wants to close the door and the water between 1.55m and 4.2m wants to open the door. This is simply 3 forces acting on a lever, where 2 are distributed over a length. The distributed forces are not hard to find though, a quick google of "distributed load moments" turned up this gem
[here](http://engineering-references.sbainvent.com/strength_of_materials/pictures/strength_of_materials_shear_moment_diagram_cantilever_triangle_distribute_increase.jpg) This is for a beam but the principles and equations are the similar, just put the pivot in a different place.

Good luck if you haven't already solved it